# C# return object as the base inherited interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I want to return an object but as the base inherited interface. IMasterData and IGetValues are shared by other projects so I am not so sure as to the amount of changes I could make. The code is like this:

```
public class WithData : IBasicData
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}

public interface IBasicData: IMasterData
{
    string prop3 { get; set; }
    string prop4 { get; set; }
}

public interface IMasterData
{
    string prop1 { get; set; }
    string prop2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IGetValues
{
    IMasterData FillValues(someType element)
}

public class MyClass : IGetValues

public IMasterData FillValues(someType element)
{
    var u = new WithData
    {
        prop1 = element.value1,
        prop2 = element.value2,
        prop3 = element.value3,
        prop4 = element.value4
    };
    return u;
}
```

I get an error in return u saying that it cannot convert the object WithData to the return type IMasterData. Due to the inheritance chain I thought it would be possible. How can I return the object as the IMasterData type?

Comment: have you tried cast? return u as IMasterData

Comment: I get an exception, "Unable to cast object of type 'WithData' to type 'IMasterData'."

Comment: Very weird, your code works fine here, can you provide the error given by the compiler?

Comment: Are you sure that is the error? `WithData` inherits from `IBasicData` with in turn inherits `IMasterData`, so in theory, it should work. And, I successfully tested it with a compiler as well.

Comment: That inheritance hierarchy works just fine for me when I create a sample app. Are you sure that's a representative example?

Comment: Other than you missing an implementation of `someType` your code compiles just fine.  You'll need to provide an example that can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: I looked deeper and noticed that ReSharper complained about the fact that there was no type that inherited from both WithData and IMasterData. So I created a new class --> WithDetailedData :  WithData, IMasterData, and changed var u  to new WithDetailedData. Seems to work.

Comment: Look at capitalizing your code correctly. It helps in understanding the code. Properties should have upper case as in `public string Prop4 { get; set; }`, and types also `SomeType element`.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely your code and it runs fine. So unless you indicate where the problem is we cannot help you much.

[image: src]

```
public interface IMasterData
{
    string Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IBasicData : IMasterData
{
    string Prop3 { get; set; }
    string Prop4 { get; set; }
}

public class WithData : IBasicData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType
{
    public string value1, value2, value3, value4;
}

public interface IGetValues
{
    IMasterData FillValues(SomeType element);
}

public class MyClass : IGetValues
{
    public IMasterData FillValues(SomeType element)
    {
        var u=new WithData()
        {
            Prop1=element.value1,
            Prop2=element.value2,
            Prop3=element.value3,
            Prop4=element.value4
        };
        return u;
    }
}
```